# How to efficiently check if a value passed to a view is nil or empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I have the following code in my application.erb file:

```
<%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, :id => "cart") do %>
```

This works fine unless I load a page that does not receive the @cart.line_items object, when I receive the following error:

```
undefined method `line_items' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I rewrite the line from my `.erb` file to have it behave the same if `@cart.line_items` is empty and if `@cart` is nil?

---

**Based on the below answers, I changed my code to use:**

```
<%= hidden_div_if(!@cart.nil? && @cart.line_items.empty?, :id => "cart") do %>
```

*Updated to match the comment Baldrick added to this question (as it is more concise than my original edit).

Comment: It's just a detail: you can write it `<%= hidden_div_if(!@cart.nil? && @cart.line_items.empty?, :id => "cart") do %>...<% end %>` to be more concise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@cart.blank?` to check whether it is nil or empty. The `blank?` method is a rails extension.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/Object.html#M000024) method of Object class.

An object is blank if it‘s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, "", " ", nil, [], and {} are blank.
For example

```
 [].blank? #true
 "".blank? #true
 "       ".blank? #true
 false.blank? #true
 {}.blank? #true
 nil.blank? #true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= hidden_div_if(@cart.to_a.line_items.empty?, :id => "cart") do %>
```